# What Widget to use for a small Pop Up from the bottom of the screen Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a small pop up screen that pops up from the bottom of the screen when something is pressed, While not being directed to another dart file and the previous screen can be darkened and seen. I've tried searching for the widget but I cant find the one im looking for.

Picture for example of what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Modal Bottom Sheet** for this. Please follow [this link](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/modal-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-dae05debbed2) or go through the doc from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

For example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```